# How to diff two keyword lists?

Tags: shell, diff

I have two files of version information of the following shape:

```
$ cat file1
cabal 2.2.0.1
http 4000.3.12
hunit 1.6.0.0
only 0.1
...
```

I'm looking for (preferably simple) ways to compare these using command line tools, allowing me to generate things such as
1. all lines in `file1` where the name doesn't show up in `file2` at all
2. lines of the form `name <v1> <v2>` for names that show up in both files

I thought I had the right ingredient when I discovered `diff -y`, but that sometimes puts different names on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

1. all lines in `file1` where the name doesn't show up in `file2` at all

Requires GNU awk for sorted results.

```
$ gawk 'NR == FNR { packages[$1] = $0; next }
        { delete packages[$1] }
        END { PROCINF0["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc";
              for (p in packages) print packages[p] }' file1 file2
```

2. lines of the form `name <v1> <v2>` for names that show up in both files

This one requires the files to be sorted on the first column.

```
$ join file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a deficient solution I came up with, using python:

```
> a = open('file1').read().splitlines()
> a = [l.split() for l in a]
> a = {k: v for (k, v) in a}
# same for b
> diff = {k: v for (k, v) in a.items() if k not in b}
> open('diff','w').write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(k, v) for (k, v) in diff.items())
```